# Python Selenium Firefox отключение курсора

Tags: python, selenium

Можно ли как нибудь отключить видимость курсора и заблокировать его в браузере, пока работает Firefox?

Comment: Что значит "заблокировать его в браузере"?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov чтобы если я случайно мышку задену курсор не появлялся и не появлялись элементы видео в браузере, полоса состояния, название фильма, элементы управления и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос про курсор мыши в Windows, то его отключить нельзя, судя по консенсусу на англо-язычных ресурсах. Можно только сделать его невидимым, путём всяких левых ухищрений.

- [Disabling mouse/cursor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/761da6fe-ea75-44f7-9ac2-c5a9e0aa389b/disabling-mousecursor?forum=w7itproui)
- [Hide Mouse Cursor on Windows with Mouse Pointer Scheme](http://www.jholjhaal.com/hide-mouse-cursor-on-windows-with-mouse-pointer-scheme/)
- [How to Hide Mouse Cursor in Windows 10 When Idle](https://www.howto-connect.com/hide-mouse-cursor-windows-10-idle/)
- [Making the mouse cursor disappear?](https://superuser.com/questions/162938/making-the-mouse-cursor-disappear)